# laravel 400 bad request

Tags: laravel

Только установил laravel, установил в существующую директорию, она названа не public, но находится на том же уровне. PHP 7.1.17, по https всё работает как надо, по http 400 bad request (другие скрипты работают).
error_reporting включал, ничего так не показывается.
Роуты никакие не писал, просто установил.
Как исправить?

Comment: Конфиг nginx покажите.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DHJMhvHk apache там всё ок по-моему, работают ведь другие скрипты

Comment: Не в том ли дело, что у вас для http прописан RewriteRule ?

Comment: не прописывал нигде, .htaccess стандартный от laravel https://pastebin.com/s2AbsJXd

Comment: Но включен он у вас только для http почему-то.

Comment: это где именно?

Comment: да, причина в той строке была, спасибо

Comment: Рад, что помогло)